# simple-slider.js - slider bar output into different html textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I've downloaded the simple-slider.js from github (https://github.com/loopj/jquery-simple-slider) and been customizing it
for my needs and now I'm stuck, from my understanding its a textbox slider.

I'm trying to get the output it displays in the "span" it creates and put it
into a different textbox under id="bitcoin" on the page instead just below the slider and update it real-time when you move the slider. see picture below to understand better.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvnNF.png
Can someone point me in the right direction? thank you.

```html
<input type="text" data-slider="true" value="0.002" data-slider-highlight="true">
<br>

<script>
  $("[data-slider]")
    .each(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      $("<span>")
        .addClass("output")
        .insertAfter($(this));
    })
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function(event, data) {
      $(this)
        .nextAll(".output:first")
        .html(data.value.toFixed(6) + " BTC");
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="bitcoin">Bitcoin</input>
```

Comment: take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dy6zyLax/2/) fiddle is it what you want or i'm misunderstood something?

Comment: It is exactly what I want! can you explain to me how you did that?
 $("#bitcoin").val(data.value.toFixed(6) + " BTC");
that's it?

Comment: Ohh that's great i have added answer as well kindly mark as answered for future references to know how to do this please find [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: yes that's all on change of slider updated value will bind to textbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at below snippet it'll work as per your expactations

```js
/*
 jQuery Simple Slider
 Copyright (c) 2012 James Smith (http://loopj.com)
 Licensed under the MIT license (http://mit-license.org/)
*/

var __slice = [].slice,
  __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

(function($, window) {
  var SimpleSlider;
  SimpleSlider = (function() {

    function SimpleSlider(input, options) {
      var ratio,
        _this = this;
      this.input = input;
      this.defaultOptions = {
        animate: true,
        snapMid: false,
        classPrefix: null,
        classSuffix: null,
        theme: null,
        highlight: false
      };
      this.settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);
      if (this.settings.theme) {
        this.settings.classSuffix = "-" + this.settings.theme;
      }
      this.input.hide();
      this.slider = $("<div>").addClass("slider" + (this.settings.classSuffix || "")).css({
        position: "relative",
        userSelect: "none",
        boxSizing: "border-box"
      }).insertBefore(this.input);
      if (this.input.attr("id")) {
        this.slider.attr("id", this.input.attr("id") + "-slider");
      }
      this.track = this.createDivElement("track").css({
        width: "100%"
      });
      if (this.settings.highlight) {
        this.highlightTrack = this.createDivElement("highlight-track").css({
          width: "0"
        });
      }
      this.dragger = this.createDivElement("dragger");
      this.slider.css({
        minHeight: this.dragger.outerHeight(),
        marginLeft: this.dragger.outerWidth() / 2,
        marginRight: this.dragger.outerWidth() / 2
      });
      this.track.css({
        marginTop: this.track.outerHeight() / -2
      });
      if (this.settings.highlight) {
        this.highlightTrack.css({
          marginTop: this.track.outerHeight() / -2
        });
      }
      this.dragger.css({
        marginTop: this.dragger.outerHeight() / -2,
        marginLeft: this.dragger.outerWidth() / -2
      });
      this.track.mousedown(function(e) {
        return _this.trackEvent(e);
      });
      if (this.settings.highlight) {
        this.highlightTrack.mousedown(function(e) {
          return _this.trackEvent(e);
        });
      }
      this.dragger.mousedown(function(e) {
        if (e.which !== 1) {
          return;
        }
        _this.dragging = true;
        _this.dragger.addClass("dragging");
        _this.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY);
        return false;
      });
      $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
        if (_this.dragging) {
          _this.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY);
          return $("body").css({
            cursor: "pointer"
          });
        }
      }).mouseup(function(e) {
        if (_this.dragging) {
          _this.dragging = false;
          _this.dragger.removeClass("dragging");
          return $("body").css({
            cursor: "auto"
          });
        }
      });
      this.pagePos = 0;
      if (this.input.val() === "") {
        this.value = this.getRange().min;
        this.input.val(this.value);
      } else {
        this.value = this.nearestValidValue(this.input.val());
      }
      this.setSliderPositionFromValue(this.value);
      ratio = this.valueToRatio(this.value);
      this.input.trigger("slider:ready", {
        value: this.value,
        ratio: ratio,
        position: ratio * this.slider.outerWidth(),
        el: this.slider
      });
    }

    SimpleSlider.prototype.createDivElement = function(classname) {
      var item;
      item = $("<div>").addClass(classname).css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "50%",
        userSelect: "none",
        cursor: "pointer"
      }).appendTo(this.slider);
      return item;
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.setRatio = function(ratio) {
      var value;
      ratio = Math.min(1, ratio);
      ratio = Math.max(0, ratio);
      value = this.ratioToValue(ratio);
      this.setSliderPositionFromValue(value);
      return this.valueChanged(value, ratio, "setRatio");
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.setValue = function(value) {
      var ratio;
      value = this.nearestValidValue(value);
      ratio = this.valueToRatio(value);
      this.setSliderPositionFromValue(value);
      return this.valueChanged(value, ratio, "setValue");
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.trackEvent = function(e) {
      if (e.which !== 1) {
        return;
      }
      this.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY, true);
      this.dragging = true;
      return false;
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.domDrag = function(pageX, pageY, animate) {
      var pagePos, ratio, value;
      if (animate == null) {
        animate = false;
      }
      pagePos = pageX - this.slider.offset().left;
      pagePos = Math.min(this.slider.outerWidth(), pagePos);
      pagePos = Math.max(0, pagePos);
      if (this.pagePos !== pagePos) {
        this.pagePos = pagePos;
        ratio = pagePos / this.slider.outerWidth();
        value = this.ratioToValue(ratio);
        this.valueChanged(value, ratio, "domDrag");
        if (this.settings.snap) {
          return this.setSliderPositionFromValue(value, animate);
        } else {
          return this.setSliderPosition(pagePos, animate);
        }
      }
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.setSliderPosition = function(position, animate) {
      if (animate == null) {
        animate = false;
      }
      if (animate && this.settings.animate) {
        this.dragger.animate({
          left: position
        }, 200);
        if (this.settings.highlight) {
          return this.highlightTrack.animate({
            width: position
          }, 200);
        }
      } else {
        this.dragger.css({
          left: position
        });
        if (this.settings.highlight) {
          return this.highlightTrack.css({
            width: position
          });
        }
      }
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.setSliderPositionFromValue = function(value, animate) {
      var ratio;
      if (animate == null) {
        animate = false;
      }
      ratio = this.valueToRatio(value);
      return this.setSliderPosition(ratio * this.slider.outerWidth(), animate);
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.getRange = function() {
      if (this.settings.allowedValues) {
        return {
          min: Math.min.apply(Math, this.settings.allowedValues),
          max: Math.max.apply(Math, this.settings.allowedValues)
        };
      } else if (this.settings.range) {
        return {
          min: parseFloat(this.settings.range[0]),
          max: parseFloat(this.settings.range[1])
        };
      } else {
        return {
          min: 0,
          max: 1
        };
      }
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.nearestValidValue = function(rawValue) {
      var closest, maxSteps, range, steps;
      range = this.getRange();
      rawValue = Math.min(range.max, rawValue);
      rawValue = Math.max(range.min, rawValue);
      if (this.settings.allowedValues) {
        closest = null;
        $.each(this.settings.allowedValues, function() {
          if (closest === null || Math.abs(this - rawValue) < Math.abs(closest - rawValue)) {
            return closest = this;
          }
        });
        return closest;
      } else if (this.settings.step) {
        maxSteps = (range.max - range.min) / this.settings.step;
        steps = Math.floor((rawValue - range.min) / this.settings.step);
        if ((rawValue - range.min) % this.settings.step > this.settings.step / 2 && steps < maxSteps) {
          steps += 1;
        }
        return steps * this.settings.step + range.min;
      } else {
        return rawValue;
      }
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.valueToRatio = function(value) {
      var allowedVal, closest, closestIdx, idx, range, _i, _len, _ref;
      if (this.settings.equalSteps) {
        _ref = this.settings.allowedValues;
        for (idx = _i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; idx = ++_i) {
          allowedVal = _ref[idx];
          if (!(typeof closest !== "undefined" && closest !== null) || Math.abs(allowedVal - value) < Math.abs(closest - value)) {
            closest = allowedVal;
            closestIdx = idx;
          }
        }
        if (this.settings.snapMid) {
          return (closestIdx + 0.5) / this.settings.allowedValues.length;
        } else {
          return closestIdx / (this.settings.allowedValues.length - 1);
        }
      } else {
        range = this.getRange();
        return (value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min);
      }
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.ratioToValue = function(ratio) {
      var idx, range, rawValue, step, steps;
      if (this.settings.equalSteps) {
        steps = this.settings.allowedValues.length;
        step = Math.round(ratio * steps - 0.5);
        idx = Math.min(step, this.settings.allowedValues.length - 1);
        return this.settings.allowedValues[idx];
      } else {
        range = this.getRange();
        rawValue = ratio * (range.max - range.min) + range.min;
        return this.nearestValidValue(rawValue);
      }
    };

    SimpleSlider.prototype.valueChanged = function(value, ratio, trigger) {
      var eventData;
      if (value.toString() === this.value.toString()) {
        return;
      }
      this.value = value;
      eventData = {
        value: value,
        ratio: ratio,
        position: ratio * this.slider.outerWidth(),
        trigger: trigger,
        el: this.slider
      };
      return this.input.val(value).trigger($.Event("change", eventData)).trigger("slider:changed", eventData);
    };

    return SimpleSlider;

  })();
  $.extend($.fn, {
    simpleSlider: function() {
      var params, publicMethods, settingsOrMethod;
      settingsOrMethod = arguments[0], params = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
      publicMethods = ["setRatio", "setValue"];
      return $(this).each(function() {
        var obj, settings;
        if (settingsOrMethod && __indexOf.call(publicMethods, settingsOrMethod) >= 0) {
          obj = $(this).data("slider-object");
          return obj[settingsOrMethod].apply(obj, params);
        } else {
          settings = settingsOrMethod;
          return $(this).data("slider-object", new SimpleSlider($(this), settings));
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return $(function() {
    return $("[data-slider]").each(function() {
      var $el, allowedValues, settings, x;
      $el = $(this);
      settings = {};
      allowedValues = $el.data("slider-values");
      if (allowedValues) {
        settings.allowedValues = (function() {
          var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
          _ref = allowedValues.split(",");
          _results = [];
          for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            x = _ref[_i];
            _results.push(parseFloat(x));
          }
          return _results;
        })();
      }
      if ($el.data("slider-range")) {
        settings.range = $el.data("slider-range").split(",");
      }
      if ($el.data("slider-step")) {
        settings.step = $el.data("slider-step");
      }
      settings.snap = $el.data("slider-snap");
      settings.equalSteps = $el.data("slider-equal-steps");
      if ($el.data("slider-theme")) {
        settings.theme = $el.data("slider-theme");
      }
      if ($el.attr("data-slider-highlight")) {
        settings.highlight = $el.data("slider-highlight");
      }
      if ($el.data("slider-animate") != null) {
        settings.animate = $el.data("slider-animate");
      }
      return $el.simpleSlider(settings);
    });
  });
})(this.jQuery || this.Zepto, this);



//Ready function

$(function(){ 
 $("[data-slider]")
    .each(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      $("<span>")
        .addClass("output")
        .insertAfter($(this));
    })
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function(event, data) {
      $(this)
        .nextAll(".output:first")
        .html(data.value.toFixed(6) + " BTC");
        $("#bitcoin").val(data.value.toFixed(6) + " BTC");
    });


});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 300px;
}

.slider > .dragger {
  background: #8DCA09;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8DCA09, #72A307);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8DCA09, #72A307);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #8DCA09, #72A307);

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  border: 1px solid #496805;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.slider > .dragger:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8DCA09, #8DCA09);
}


.slider > .track, .slider > .highlight-track {
  background: #ccc;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #ddd);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #ddd);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #ddd);

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;

  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 4px;
}

.slider > .highlight-track {
 background-color: #8DCA09;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8DCA09, #72A307);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8DCA09, #72A307);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #8DCA09, #72A307);
 
 border-color: #496805;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-slider="true" value="0.002" data-slider-highlight="true">
<input type="text" id="bitcoin" />
```